# Vector calculus of a potential energy formula under Galileo transformation

Tags: potential, vectors, differentiation, galilean-relativity

I'm currently studying MIT OCW 8.20 Introduction to Special Relativity. In pset 1, the following question is being asked:  Suppose you have a potential of the form U($\vec{r_1}, \vec{r_2}$) = U(|$\vec{r_1} - \vec{r_2}$|). Show that the
force resulting from such a potential is invariant under Galilean transformations. In the answer to this question, they first take the partial derivative of the function: $F_i = -\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}U(|\vec{r_1}-\vec{r_2}|)$. Next, they define the distance vector $r_{12}$:  $r_{12} = (|\vec{r_1} - \vec{r_2}|) = \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2 + (z_2-z_1)^2}$ and $\frac{\partial{r_{12}}}{\partial{x_i}} = \frac{x_{2,i}-x_{1,i}}{r_{12}}$. After that, they show that the derivative of $r_{12}$ remains unchanged when applying Galilean transformations. I get stuck at the second step. How do they go from $r_{12} = (|\vec{r_1} - \vec{r_2}|) = \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2 + (z_2-z_1)^2}$ to $\frac{\partial{r_{12}}}{\partial{x_i}} = \frac{x_{2,i}-x_{1,i}}{r_{12}}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we consider $r=|\bf{x}|$ for a vector $\bf{x}$, we can work out $\frac{\partial r^2}{\partial x_i}$ in two ways:

Firstly,$\frac{\partial r^2}{\partial x_i}=\frac{\partial x_j x_j }{\partial x_i}=2\delta_{ij}x_j=2x_i$.

Secondly, $\frac{\partial r^2}{\partial x_i}=\frac{\partial r^2}{\partial r} \frac{\partial{r}}{\partial{x_i}}=2r \frac{\partial{r}}{\partial{x_i}}$.

Setting these equal to each other, we get $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_i}=\frac{x_i}{r}$. (1)

In the context of your question, setting $\bf{x}=\bf{x_1}-\bf{x_2}$ (and therefore $x_i=x_{1,i}-x_{2,i}$) and $r=r_{12}=r_1-r_2$ in Eq. (1) gives you your desired result.